# Overriding a JVM method using Kotlin property

Tags: kotlin

`MyKotlinClass` is implementing `ThirdPartyJavaInterface`.

---

**ThirdPartyJavaInterface**

```
public interface ThirdPartyJavaInterface {
    String getName();
}
```

---

**MyKotlinClass**

```
class MyKotlinClass (val name: String) : ThirdPartyJavaInterface
```

---

`MyKotlinClass` is not getting compiled because of `Accidental Override` error for `getName()` method by `name` field.

I do want to override the `getName()` intentionally. Is there any way to suppress the error by telling the compiler my intention?

One possible solution in my mind is as below but I don't want to write this much code (because in actual scenario I have 8 methods to override)

```
class MyKotlinClass (val aName: String) : ThirdPartyJavaInterface {
    override fun getName(): String {
        return aName
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add an `override` modifier to the variable? Or, can you move the variable out of the constructor, and then add the `override`  to that?